# catalog price rules in magento 2.1.4 and 2.1.5

Tags: magento-2.1.4, magento2.1.5

I tried to apply catalog price rules from Magento backend, But it did not work out in fronted.
I cleared cache, indexing still its not working.I think this is bug for Magento versions 2.1.4 and 2.1.5.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was related to improper installation or Magento as well as Sample Data.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure you have applied the Created catalog price rules.**

**Follow the below steps :**

1. Logged in to your magento admin panel
2. Click on marketing -> catalog price rules
3. Add your rules with proper condition !! it will only show if your
   condition is matched .
4. Click on save and apply button .
5. if you have clicked on only save then rule is not applied
6. To Apply the rule click on Apply rules
7. The run command php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: I tried it all pal !! but still did not worked for me..